# Qt QNetworkAccessManager exception

Tags: c++, qt, exception, qnetworkaccessmanager, qt5.2

I have some weird behavior of the `QNetworkAccessManager` Qt class.
Basically whenever I do:

```
QNetworkAccessManager *worker = new QNetworkAccessManager();
```

I get:

> Exception at 0x75a1c41f, code: 0x6a6: Invalid RPC server, flags=0x1
>   (execution cannot be continued) (first chance)

The exception is thrown when debugger reaches the line containing `new QNetworkAccessManager();`. I'm doing the test in the mainform, so no threads running, nothing could be causing memory break or something like that. I'm using Qt 5.2.0 with mscv2012 compiler. I think this error results in later that I get some garbage in server response like so:

```
   <div style="display: none;" class="report-link-dialog-loading"></div>

   <div class="report-link-dialog-content">
   <p>You are about to flag this item as unappropriate.</p>
   <form id='report-content-form' action='/'>
       <div>
       <input id="report_content_type" name="report_content_type" type="hidden" value=""/>
       <input id="report_content_id" name="report_content_id" type="hidden" value="test"/>
       <input id="report_content_url" name="report_content_url" type="hidden" value=""/>
       <textarea name="report_content_comment" id="report_content_comment" rows="5" cols="20"></textarea>
       </div>
   </form>
   </div>
   </div>


   </body>
   </html>
ggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg
```

Can someone PLEASE help!!

Comment: A report of a similar bug has been filed: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-36180

Comment: According to my experiment, the QNetworkAccessManager has quite a lot of problems, if you are on windows, just try WinHttp~